# Resize Table based on Filtered table in another sheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy the datarange from one table on a worksheet to the datarange on another table in a different worksheet. I do not want to take the header contents, and ideally I'd like to figure out how to remove the far left column, but I need it to filter.

I'm trying to figure out how to resize the table I'm attempting to paste the values into based on the size of the table I'm copying the range from.

```
Sub AdjustedTablebyDistrict()
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tbl2 As ListObject
Dim tbl3 As ListObject
Dim tbl4 As ListObject

'Identify tables for paste job
Set tbl = Worksheets("BaseSheet").ListObjects("Table1")
Set tbl2 = Worksheets("BaseSheet").ListObjects("Table2")
'Identify tables for copy job
Set tbl3 = Worksheets("Step7Table").ListObjects("Step7")
Set tbl4 = Worksheets("Step2Table").ListObjects("Table4")

'Set to number of (districts -1) Currently 48
 For i = 0 To 9

Dim districtName As Range

With tbl3

'Change Tables based on selected District from dropdown
Worksheets("BaseSheet").Range("T1") =     Worksheets("BaseSheet").Range("U2").Offset(i, 0)
Set districtName = Worksheets("BaseSheet").Range("T1")
ThisFile = districtName.Value

'Filter on selected district
tbl3.Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=districtName


Dim rng As Range
'Find size of copy table
numRows = tbl3.DataBodyRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
numCols = tbl3.Range.Columns.Count

'Resize table for paste
tbl2.Resize tbl2.Range.Resize(numRows, numCols)

tbl3.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=tbl2

End With

Next i

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Edit: Was able to find a way to get the range and resize to run, but it's not functioning properly. The Table doesn't shrink even if the values for rows become smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of the code

```
tbl2.Resize tbl2.Range.Resize(numRows, numCols)
```

Answered my initial question for resizing the table. It was initially invalid because I was trying to directly resize the table without specifying the resize first. My second error, making the table "Shrink" was my own user error.

The table had actually gotten smaller but had left remnants of data from the previous run. To change this I merely had to add

```
.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
```

The full code for manipulating table resize based on filtered table from another sheet is below.

```
Dim i As Integer

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tbl2 As ListObject
Dim tbl3 As ListObject
Dim tbl4 As ListObject

'Identify tables for paste job
Set tbl = Worksheets("BaseSheet").ListObjects("Table1")
Set tbl2 = Worksheets("BaseSheet").ListObjects("Table2")
'Identify tables for copy job
Set tbl3 = Worksheets("Step7Table").ListObjects("Step7")

'Set to number of (districts -1) Currently 48
For i = 0 To 5

Dim districtName As Range
Dim ThisFile As String

With tbl3

'Change Tables based on selected District from dropdown
    Worksheets("BaseSheet").Range("T1") =           Worksheets("BaseSheet").Range("U2").Offset(i, 0)
    Set districtName = Worksheets("BaseSheet").Range("T1")
    ThisFile = districtName.Value

'Filter on selected district
    Worksheets("Step7Table").Range("A1").AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=districtName

'Find size of copy table
    countRows = ((tbl3.DataBodyRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count / 3) + 1)
    'MsgBox (tbl3.DataBodyRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count) / 3

    numRows = countRows
    'numCols = tbl3.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count

'Resize table for paste
    tbl2.Resize tbl2.Range.Resize(numRows)

    tbl3.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=tbl2

    'Add total row
    tbl2.ShowTotals = True
    tbl2.TotalsRowRange(, 1) = "Total"
    'tbl2.TotalsRowRange(, 2).Formula =
    'Call save functionality for each district
    Call saveToExcel(ThisFile)
    With tbl2
    'Turn off total row for row resets. Currently counts as part of datarange
        .ShowTotals = False
    'Clear table so that is can be reformatted without leave legacy contents
        .DataBodyRange.ClearFormats
        .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    End With
    'Turn off total row for row resets. Currently counts as part of datarange

End With

Next i

'Enables alert messages
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Refresh screen after code runs fully
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```